# Chromium inline style is not allowing correct view

Tags: javascript, css, chromium

Ican not see blah blah when a contains style like below.

```
 <a data-toggle="sth" style="float:left">blah blah</a>
```

I tried below too but it gives an unwanted result

```
<a data-toggle="sth" style="float:'left'">blah blah</a>
```

In chrome and firefox it runs as expected.

I am using  javascript libraries and jquery, i do not know if they are the problem

Comment: You can not see it where? give the parent container an overflow maybe. Your question is unclear

Comment: First one is right & it's working http://jsfiddle.net/Yh9FN/

Comment: Don't try another style, coz your first style is exactly right, We didnt understand, what do you mean by "Ican not see blah blah" - its not taking float:left or hiding element, or miss aligning that blah blah...If possible update jsfiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/x8rs5/1/  no error here, i think there are problems about my backing css or js libraries

Answer (score 2):

```
<a data-toggle="sth" style="float:left;">blah blah</a>
```

Comment: @tuxi you have not used semicolon. semicolon is required in style property.

Comment: it's not for the last defined style i believe

Comment: sorry @RakeshHolkar for wrong code, i have semicolon in original